# I can not output the data in the template of handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, async-await, handlebars.js

I get data on an async request. I pass the data to the function and break them on rows. How to pass a rows to a template

```
async function upComing() {

    const { results } = await $.ajax ("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=******************&language=en-US&page="+numberPage);
    const { genres } = await $.ajax ("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=******************&language=en-US");

    const movies = results.map(({genre_ids, ...rest}) => {
      const filteredIds = genres.filter(gen => genre_ids.includes(gen.id)); 
      const genreNames = filteredIds.map(gen_id => gen_id.name);

      return {
        ...rest,
        genreNames,
      };
    });

    const splittedArray = splitArray(movies);

    function splitArray(arr) {
      var result = [];
      let row = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const rowIndex = result.length;
        const len = rowIndex & 1 ? 2 : 4 ;
        row.push(arr[i]);
        if (row.length === len) {
          result.push(row);
          row = [];
        }
      }
      if (row.length) {
        result.push(row);
      }
      return result;
    }

    const source = document.getElementById("item").innerHTML;
    const template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    const html = template(splittedArray);
    var numberPage = 1;

    $(".content_movie").html(html);

upComing();
```

Comment: Hi, i'd like to help you, but could you provide me an example of json?

Comment: 1. (7) [Array(4), Array(2), Array(4), Array(2), Array(4), Array(2), Array(2)]
 0:(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 1:(2) [{…}, {…}]
 2:(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 3:(2) [{…}, {…}]
 4:(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 5:(2) [{…}, {…}]
 6:(2) [{…}, {…}]

Comment: Hi! one more question.  For that are you used this? const len = rowIndex & 1 ? 2 : 4;

Comment: I have been trying to solve your problem and found how you can have achieved it, but there is one more problem, do you still need to my help?

Comment: @VadimNikiforov Perhaps it will be more clear what I want to do if you look at my code  https://github.com/slemik1/movie42

Comment: @VadimNikiforov the problem arises here movie42/src/js/main.js line 90

Comment: You are welcome, you can mark your answer as right and up vote my if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
It was necessary to make a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper ('isEqual', function (v1, v2, options) {
if (v1 === v2) {
return options.fn (this);
}
return options.inverse (this);
});
```

And change the template:

```
{{#each splittedArray}}
        {{#isEqual this.length 4 }}
            <div class="row">
                {{#each .}}
                    <div class="item_4">
                        <div class="container">
                        <a class="buttonFavoriteMovie" data-id="{{id}}" onclick="buttonFavoriteMovie({{id}})" href="/"></a> 
                        <a class="moveMovieInfo" onclick="movieSelected({{id}})" href="/item.html">
                        <img class="poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300{{poster_path}}" onError="this.src='../img/No_image_available.png'" alt="{{title}}">
                        <h3 class="title">{{title}}</h3>
                        <h4 id="categories">{{genreNames}}</h4>
                        </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}      
            </div>
        {{else}}
            <div class="row">
             {{#each .}}
                    <div class="item_2">
                        <div class="container">
                        <a class="buttonFavoriteMovie" data-id="{{id}}" onclick="buttonFavoriteMovie({{id}})" href="/"></a> 
                        <a class="moveMovieInfo" onclick="movieSelected({{id}})" href="/item.html">
                        <img class="poster" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300{{poster_path}}" onError="this.src='../img/No_image_available.png'" alt="{{title}}">
                        <h3 class="title">{{title}}</h3>
                        <h4 id="categories">{{genreNames}}</h4>
                        </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{/isEqual}}
        {{/each}}
```

and I have an error here:

```
 const html = template({splittedArray});
changed to
 const html = template({splittedArray});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to solve your problem, i din't have found a correct answer, because of

Input:

```
Search:(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Output:

```
result : Array(3)
   0: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   1: (2) [{…}, {…}]
   2: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

But i have fixed a few errors and i still don't understand what do you try to achieve? I think that's impossible, because you need to provide a object name like this:

```
{
  people: [
   {firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz"},
   {firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Lerche"},
   {firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson"}
  ]
}
```

When you can use a template such as:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each result}}<article>
    <h4>{{Title}} <small>({{Year}})</small></h4>
  </article>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Here what i have done take and look  [a link to the code](https://jsfiddle.net/nikifovadim/7xemLt6j/7/)